# Dynamic number of columns grouped - datatables jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

[image: Dynamic number of columns grouped by specific properties]

I am trying to fetch data from my API and present it in a way that it is grouped by shipment type (Shipment Type A and Shipment Type B in the diagram). Each shipment type has different weight categories and each weight has specific price value for a country. For example,

Shipment Type A - Germany - Weight = 1kg - has price = 20€

and so on. Idea is to utilize datatables sort and search filters to be easily search for sepcific shipment type and country. Also, make these price column inline editable.

Since the whole project uses [jQuery based datatables](https://datatables.net), I wanted to stick with it however I couldn't find a way to achieve this with datatables.

I checked, https://datatables.net/extensions/rowgroup/examples/initialisation/multipleGroups.html

and tried customize it which is the closest I could find, but couldn't find a way to achieve this.

Something like this and be able to utilize search and sort feature of datatables.

```html
<table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="5">DHL</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Germany</td>
                    <td>20</td><td>30</td><td>40</td><td>50</td><td>60</td>                    
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Austria</td>
                    <td>120</td><td>130</td><td>140</td><td>X</td><td>610</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="5">UPS</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Germany</td>
                    <td>20</td><td>30</td><td>40</td><td>50</td><td>60</td>                    
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Austria</td>
                    <td>120</td><td>130</td><td>140</td><td>X</td><td>610</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following example is based on the demo [here](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/row_grouping.html).

This is a single row grouping (not a multi-row grouping) since the example data in the question only has a single group.

It uses the following standard scripts and CSS files, with the addition of two "row group" plug-in files:

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Demo</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
  <!-- this next one is optional: -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://datatables.net/media/css/site-examples.css">

  <!-- row group plugin -->
  <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/rowgroup/1.0.2/css/rowGroup.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/rowgroup/1.0.2/js/dataTables.rowGroup.min.js"></script>

</head>
```

The test data is as follows:

```
<table id="example" class="display dataTable cell-border" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Shipment Type</th>
            <th>Country</th>
            <th>Weight Category</th>
            <th>Price</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Shipment Type A</td>
            <td>Germany</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>20</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Shipment Type A</td>
            <td>Germany</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>30</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Shipment Type A</td>
            <td>Germany</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>40</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Shipment Type A</td>
            <td>Austria</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>90</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Shipment Type A</td>
            <td>Austria</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>120</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Shipment Type A</td>
            <td>Austria</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>140</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Shipment Type B</td>
            <td>Germany</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>30</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Shipment Type B</td>
            <td>Germany</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>40</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Shipment Type B</td>
            <td>Germany</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>55</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Shipment Type B</td>
            <td>Austria</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>40</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Shipment Type B</td>
            <td>Austria</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>100</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Shipment Type B</td>
            <td>Austria</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>100</td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Shipment Type</th>
            <th>Country</th>
            <th>Weight Category</th>
            <th>Price</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

The DataTables initialization code is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var collapsedGroups = {};
var dtable;

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "pageLength": 50,
        rowGroup: {
            dataSrc: 0,

            startRender: function(rows, group) {
                var collapsed = !!collapsedGroups[group];
                rows.nodes().each(function (r) {
                    r.style.display = collapsed ? 'none' : '';
                });    

                var toggleClass = collapsed ? 'fas fa-chevron-up' : 'fas fa-chevron-down';

                // Add category name to the <tr>. NOTE: Hardcoded colspan
                return $('<tr/>')
                    .append('<td colspan="' + rows.columns()[0].length + 
                            '"><i class="'+ toggleClass + '"></i> ' + 
                            group + ' (' + rows.count() + ')</td>')
                    .attr('data-name', group)
                    .toggleClass('collapsed', collapsed);
            }

        }

    } );
} );

</script>
```

The end result looks like this:

[image]

The data can be sorted and filtered in the usual way.

Comment: Thank you, but with your example, weight and price are arranged in different columns, what we need is, each weight gets its own column.

Comment: @roko My mistake. What does the source JSON look like? Could you add a representative sample?